# How to create custom object (database table) in Salesforce with python

Tags: python, salesforce, salesforce-communities, simple-salesforce

When attempting to create a custom object using Python requests, an "INVALID_FIELD" error was encountered.

```
import requests

 
headers = {
'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

url = f'{base_url}/services/data/v52.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomObject'

payload = {
'FullName': 'MyCustomObject__c',
'Label': 'My Custom Object',
'PluralLabel': 'My Custom Objects',
'DeploymentStatus': 'Deployed',
'SharingModel': 'ReadWrite',
'Fields': [
    {
        'FullName': 'Name__c',
        'Label': 'Name',
        'Type': 'Text',
        'Length': 200,
        'Required': True,
        'Description': 'The name of the record'
    },
    {
        'FullName': 'Age__c',
        'Label': 'Age',
        'Type': 'Text',
        'Length': 50,
        'Required': True,
        'Description': 'The Age of the record'
    }
]
}
response = requests.post(url, json=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 201:
    print('Custom object created successfully.')
else:
    print('Failed to create custom object.')
    print('Response:', response.json())
```

I want to ensure that the payload and URL I have for creating a custom object in Salesforce are valid.